# Convert a data-table into a class object dynamically using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Are there any inbuild methods in .Net where a datatable can be converted into a poco class object.

For better understanding of my scenario, please go through below,

I have a specific requirement where i would get multiple data tables like shown below

```
Name                 ||         Value
---------------------------------------
DashboardName        ||         DashBoard1
myparam1             ||         abc
myparam2             ||         def
myparam3             ||         xyz
type                 ||         MyClass


Name                    ||         Value
    ---------------------------------------
    DashboardName        ||         DashBoard2
    myparamnew           ||         abc
    myparamnew2          ||         def
    myparamnew3          ||         xyz
    type                 ||         MyClass2
```

I have two classes

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string myparam1{ get; set; }
  public string myparam2{ get; set; }
  public string myparam3{ get; set; }
}

public class MyClass2
{
 public string myparamnew1{ get; set; }
 public string myparamnew2{ get; set; }
 public string myparamnew3{ get; set; }
}
```

So based on the type value of the datatable I want to convert the datatable into that type specific class.

Can some one guide me towards a right direction to achieve my objective?

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) can be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has no inbuild method in .Net as I know but there has some 3rd party support or [EntityFramework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/bb399567(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you don't want to use 3rd party library, you can try T4 Template to implement.

3rd party..
[Poco-Generator](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/892233/POCO-Generator)